# Why does same code gives different addresses each time it runs?

Tags: c, operating-system, stack, malloc, heap-memory

I get different values as output each time I run the code. When heap and stack addresses are fixed why does malloc return a different address?
I expected it to start allocating from top of heap and return a fixed address each time. Similarly for stack.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int *ptr = malloc(128);
    int a;
    printf("%p %p\n", ptr, &a);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: [Improvements in security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) are deliberately messing with you. That's my guess anyways.

Comment: @Amadan but every process gets it's own virtual memory address space. which means that with aslr turned off it should have the same addess every time

Comment: On an exemplary Win10 only the heap address changes, the address of `a` is fixed. You could also print the address of `main()` to watch the code space, too, like this: `printf("%p %p %p\n", ptr, &a, main);`. Again, fixed on this exemplary Win10.

Comment: OT: The conversion specifier `p` is defined for `void`-pointers only, so to print the value of a pointer with a type different from `void*` cast it to the latter: `printf("%p %p\n", (void*) ptr, (void*) &a);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heap and stack addresses are not fixed. Some systems use [address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) to deliberately vary the addresses so that attackers will not have predictable addresses to use with exploits.

Comment: I now understand aslr, but when you say "Heap and stack addresses are not fixed" do you mean in general, right? It is fixed for a particular binary (if we forget aslr for a moment), correct?

Comment: @Sandy: When ASLR is in use, each time the program is loaded, the loader will pick a random base address. If ASLR is not in use, then, generally, one address is used for all programs, every time a program is loaded.